# How to access s3 bucket in ec2 windows instance using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have been using EC2 windows instance and installed AWS CLI in it, I have created IAM user with CLI access credential and with full s3 access permission and I had install AWS CLI in my personal system. Now the problem is that I can access the s3 bucket using CLI credential in my system but not in EC2 instance CLI.

Here I provide the error I got

An error occurred (AuthorizationHeaderMalformed) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The authorization header is malformed; the authorization header requires three components: Credential, SignedHeaders, and Signature.

Comment: That is a very strange error message. One thing to check... is the Date and Time set correctly on the instance? If not, the signature can be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You should grant s3 permissions to your instance's IAM role instead. 
Then you won't even have to do any profile configuration on the instance.

Comment: Thanks for the response Gergely, I have attached IAM role to the instance with s3 full access.